# How to check for `--keepdb` flag in Django

Tags: django

I've created an `AppConfig` that uses the `post_migrate` signal to run some extra SQL every time I do a migration.  In my tests sometimes I use `--keepdb` to speed up running the tests but it's still triggering the `post_migrate` signal.  How can I check to see if the `--keepdb` flag was used so I can skip running my extra SQL commands?  I've looked in the Django documentation and the source code and I can't seem to find any way to do that.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve this by creating a TestRunner that stores the `--keepdb` flag on the settings like this:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.test.runner import DiscoverRunner


class KeepDBTestRunner(DiscoverRunner):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        settings.KEEP_DB = kwargs.get('keepdb', False)
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```